# Can't start the karma server in angular

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

Hi I'm trying to get the test script running on the angular tutorial (step 2, writing and running test part 1) but I'm stuck at trying to run the karma server but when I run the command in the GitBash terminal I get this error

```
John@JOHN-PC ~/angular-phonecat ((step-2))
$ ./scripts/test.sh

Starting Karma Server (http://karma-runner.github.io)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
    Can not find the binary C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Applic
ation\chrome.exe
    Please set env variable CHROME_BIN
```

any idea what this means

here's the link to the tutorial http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02

Comment: @Christian Ternus yeah so I made a new variable CHROME_BIN in both the system and user variable and tried to run the command again and still gave me the same erro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Cristian Ternus had already pointed out you will have to set the correct value of the `CHROME_BIN` env variable. Dont copy the path as it is provided in the comment. You will have to find out where `crome.exe` is present on your machine. Please refer http://bardevblog.wordpress.com/2013/07/28/setting-up-angularjs-angular-seed-node-js-and-karma/ which is a nice tutorial about running angular test cases. Step 8 in the tutorial is addressing your issue.

Comment: Step 8 works, but even though I just installed karma yesterday per Google tutorial instructions, I got a message saying karma-junit-reporter was not installed. The message also has a node command to install this reporter. It works. After installation, enter scripts\test.bat, and you should get a Karma server started message.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Google Chrome installed? If not, install it.

If it's installed, is it in that path (`C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Applic
ation\chrome.exe`)?

If not, [set the environment variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) `CHROME_BIN` to the path of `chrome.exe`.

Comment: thanks so far, but I'm a little new to this. but do I make a new variable CHORME_BIN or is it already in there? where do I set chrome_bin? in the system variables or user variable?

Comment: It needs to be visible to the Karma server process; the system variables should work. I don't know if it's already there -- you should check in your own list. (I don't have a Windows machine handy.)

Comment: Yeah so It's not in list but i did add CHROME_BIN and I did add to the path that you wrote and it  still won't work =/

Comment: If you don't have Chrome installed and configured, step 9 in the bardevblog cited in the above checked answer tells how to do it.